# JSON JQ - filter with two statements

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm using the below which is working perfectly but I want to add one more variable to the filtering, preferably "contains" as I want to filter this one based on a OS field which contains different strings:

> curl -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4" -H "Authorization: Token $token" "$url_devices" -k | jq -r --arg device "$device" '.results[] | **select(.cluster.name == $cluster)** | .primary_ip.address'

Thank you in advance! I tried the following code, but it didn't work:

> curl -H "Accept: application/json; indent=4" -H "Authorization: Token $token" "$url_devices" -k | jq -r --arg device "$device" '.results[] | **select(.cluster.name == $cluster AND .cluster.os == $os)** | .primary_ip.address'

Comment: Use (another) `--arg` option to define more external values. (Note that in your "working" approach, only defining a `device` variable, and then using `$cluster` instead will not work.) As for a "field which contains different strings", you'd need to be more specific to get help on that.

Comment: [`and` is a lower-case operator](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#and-or-not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily chain multiple `select` filters:

```
.results[]
| select(.cluster.name == $cluster)
| select(.cluster.os == $os)
| .primary_ip.address
```

or combine multiple predicates with [`and`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#and-or-not) (note the case):

```
.results[]
| select(.cluster.name == $cluster and .cluster.os == $os)
| .primary_ip.address
```

The result is identical.

To check if a string [`contains`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#contains) another substring, you'd use:

```
.results[]
| select(.cluster.name == $cluster)
| select(.cluster.os | contains($os))
| .primary_ip.address
```